# Best practices for lookup tables in the application - by id or value

Tags: programming-practices, lookup

I have a complex database application. There are a lot of lookup tables containing a few values, in particular one contains pass / fail / waiting / unknown.

In the application I find many of the queries depend on the pass/fail status of a model. So I want to display everything with a pass. Or everything that isn't a fail.

I am using Django (though I am sure the question is relevant outside of Django).

So when I am querying via the ORM, I can join the extra table in and say for example.

```
Model.objects.filter(passfail__status='pass')
```

Alternatively I can use the ID.

```
Model.objects.filter(passfail_id=1)
```

The first example will join in the passfail table and query based on the "status" field - the actual text 'pass' / 'fail' / 'waiting' text.

Is either of these considered good / bad practice?

Using the ID should be slightly better performance, as there is one less join. And it will avoid the problem of the passfail status changing (it shouldn't but I never know what users will do).

Using the status field should make the code more readable and more obvious what we are trying to achive. Though I don't expect the passfail table to change.

Comment: What else is in the passfail table?  If all it has is id and status then just drop the table completely.  I used to make a gazillion look up tables but gradually shifted to getting rid of them if there was no realistic chance of them needing to be changed.

Comment: pass fail waiting and unknown. It may get updated in the future, not likely, but always a possibility. (I think it started as a boolean).

Comment: Not the values but the columns themselves.  If the table holds only one piece of useful information per row then it might be that the table itself is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

Use **enums**. Good ORM framework can easily handle mapping of enums to IDs. Then you benefit two ways:

1. **Simple use in code and clear business logic** - you operate (compare, etc.) on descriptive names, so business logic is clear.
2. **Performance efficiency**: No joins for descriptive names in db queries (ORM will operate on Ids only)

If you can't - you can fallback to **named constants** just to make your code clear. You unfortunately won't benefit in ORM then.

Comment: Other answers recommended against using enums in case the values change or get added to. It certainly feels like a less flexible solution. Is there any reason not to go for the extra join?

Comment: If there is high variability in values then I would use a proper implementation of a dictionary. Please note that given requirements are contradictory: 1. compile time safety (enums) 2. values can be added/removed frequently. Then business rules clarity and clean code are more important than the additional join mentioned previously.